# Poisson Prediction offset weights

Tags: r, statistics

There has to be a difference between setting an offset and setting weights in a Poisson GLM

```
pois.model = glm(formula = freq_y_ac~ freq_x_ac[,14] + freq_x_ac[,15]+freq_x_ac[,18]+freq_x_ac[,19]+
                  offset(log(train_claims_ac$Exposition_au_risque)),
                 data=as.data.frame(freq_x_ac), family=poisson(link = log))

sum(predict(pois.model,type='response'))
[1] 2238
```

This is exactly the same value as the real claims.

But when I use weights instead of offset:

```
pois.model2 = glm(formula = freq_y_ac~ freq_x_ac[,14] + freq_x_ac[,15]+freq_x_ac[,18]+freq_x_ac[,19],
                  weights=train_claims_ac$Exposition_au_risque, 
                  family=poisson(link = log))

sum(predict.glm(pois.model2,type='response'))
[1] 2947.749
```

When I multiply this number with the exposure and I multiply the real claims with the exposure, I got the same values after that. But I really do not get why. In my opinion, the real claims are already mulitplied with the exposure and would have to be divided if even.

At the end I have to get an annual premium, which would be the offset outcome divided by the Exposure I guess.

Comment: It's a good idea with questions like these to create a minimal reproducible example, since we don't have your data. For example, consider that you could have used `glm(cyl ~ mpg + offset(log(wt)), data = mtcars, family = "poisson")` and `glm(cyl ~ mpg, data = mtcars, weights = wt, family = "poisson")` to show the same difference between offsets and weights, and anyone would be able to reproduce it immediately

Answer (score 0):

Weights and offsets are not the same thing, and you shouldn't be using weights for a Poisson regression.

A weight in this definition is not something that each response is multiplied by; it is a precision measure of how much we "trust" each observation. Observations with high weight will have more impact on the resulting fit than observations with a low weight.

See the [glm docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html) (emphasis mine):

> Non-NULL weights can be used to indicate that different observations have different dispersions (with the values in weights being inversely proportional to the dispersions)... For a binomial GLM prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes: **they would rarely be used for a Poisson GLM**

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The weird thing is, I use the HDtweedie Package which is for Poisson and Gamma and there only exists a weight Parameter.

Comment: @Zugi From a brief look at the HDtweedie package I *think* weights mean the same thing they do in glm. You could try using `+ offset(log(x))` to represent exposure

Comment: @DavidRobinson if you would have a look at tis post : https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/371298/121493 then you will see that it could lead to similar results, don't you agree?